# System mail from hbh_output

Tags: macos, email

Firing up the terminal today gave me a surprise, since it said I have mail.
For the first time in my life on a Mac I ran the `mail` app and it was a bounce e-mail for an unknown user:

```
From MAILER-DAEMON  Wed Aug 22 09:39:35 2018  
X-Original-To: boro@Boros-MBP.local  
Delivered-To: boro@Boros-MBP.local  
Date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 09:39:35 +0200 (CEST)  
From: MAILER-DAEMON@Boros-MBP.local (Mail Delivery System)  
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender  
To: boro@Boros-MBP.local  
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied  
MIME-Version: 1.0  
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;  
    boundary="8BFCC13E86B1.1534923575/Boros-MBP.local"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  

This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

--8BFCC13E86B1.1534923575/Boros-MBP.local  
Content-Description: Notification  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  

This is the mail system at host boros-mbp.local.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not  
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can  
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<hBh_output@Boros-MBP.local> (expanded from <hBh_output>): unknown user:
    "hbh_output"

--8BFCC13E86B1.1534923575/Boros-MBP.local  
Content-Description: Delivery report  
Content-Type: message/delivery-status  

Reporting-MTA: dns; Boros-MBP.local  
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 8BFCC13E86B1  
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; boro@Boros-MBP.local  
Arrival-Date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 09:39:35 +0200 (CEST)  

Final-Recipient: rfc822; hBh_output@Boros-MBP.local  
Original-Recipient: rfc822;hBh_output@Boros-MBP.local  
Action: failed  
Status: 5.1.1  
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "hbh_output"  

--8BFCC13E86B1.1534923575/Boros-MBP.local
Content-Description: Undelivered Message  
Content-Type: message/rfc822  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit  

Return-Path: <boro@Boros-MBP.local>  
Received: by Boros-MBP.local (Postfix, from userid 501)  
    id 8BFCC13E86B1; Wed, 22 Aug 2018 09:39:35 +0200 (CEST)  
To: hBh_output@Boros-MBP.local  
Subject: Boros-MBP.local -h run output  
Message-Id: <20180822073935.8BFCC13E86B1@Boros-MBP.local>  
Date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 09:39:35 +0200 (CEST)  
From: boro@Boros-MBP.local


Wed Aug 22 09:39:35 CEST 2018  

--8BFCC13E86B1.1534923575/Boros-MBP.local--
```

I have absolutely no idea what's hBh and where this came from.
Anybody got a clue?

Comment: Could you add the mail header of the non-delivery report to your question to provide more context? Is `oros-MBP` the name of you Mac?

Comment: @jaume Just added the complete contents. Yes, Boros-MBP is the nema of the Mac.

Comment: Thanks, some thoughts: (1) since there is only one instance of this mail (correct me if I'm wrong) I rule out a misconfiguration of a system component (2) your user account has generated the message (`From: boro@Boros-MBP.local`) (3) the message has no body (4) the subject (`Boros-MBP.local -h run output`) has drawn my attention, could you check your Bash history to see if you have run some command (possibly with the `-h` option) on August 22nd 09:39 (run `less .bash_history`, press `G` to move to the end of the file and press `B` to scroll up)? Which macOS version does your Mac run?